# Views search for term reference in field collection

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, search

I have content type where tagged persons names are automatically saved as a taxonomy term. These created terms have a field, which is a field collection of a date and another taxonomy term which keeps information about the unit. What I'm trying to achieve is, to search for nodes via the unit taxonomy term which will bring up nodes where persons from this unit are tagged. I have no clue how to get it work. I guess somewhere under relationships or contextual filters should be the options but so far I wasn't able to figure it out.

Node

- title
- Person (taxonomy term)

  - date / unit (taxonomy term in a field collection field of taxonomy term above)
- image

Comment: Extremely complex. When I encounter something like this, I first try to create a view using the required relationships that will show the node and the data I need, in this case "node title" and "unit". Then, if I can do that, I create an exposed text filter for that field and if I'm lucky, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by adding a relation with the field which holds the taxonomy term data for persons. A second relation needed to be added, this time related to the field collection name. This way I'm now able to expose the field which holds the job data as a search option.